# SUMO Traffic Simulation Induction Loops on Multiple Lanes

Tags: network-traffic, sumo, traffic-simulation

In the real world, aggregated data from induction loops is usually measured across all lanes of the road. As I try to model traffic demand from real world Data, which holds the number of vehicles that passed a specific induction loop, I wonder what is best practice to place these Induction loops within my net.

Is there a way in SUMO to place an induction loop across all lanes of an Edge ?

Or

Is there a way to group single Induction
loops within a higher level XML-Tag and get retrieve the collected data from the group ?

(The background of these Question is the intended use of the DfRouter for multilane Edges)

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way of grouping the detectors in the input or defining loops which cover multiple lanes. DFRouter (and also flowrouter) however groups them automatically based on their position on the lane.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to group them in one file is giving them the same "file" to output their data. For induction loops at different positions I use different output files to separate them.
Here is my code as an example
I created a loop for every lane and named them with the number of the loop and the number of the lane

```
<!-- AtoB; speed=60 km/h; 2 lanes -->
<inductionLoop id="AtoB-2.1(auto)" lane="27333102.218.2368_0" pos="250" freq="60" file="file1(auto).out.xml" freindlyPos="true" vTypes="auto"/>
<inductionLoop id="AtoB-2.2(auto)" lane="27333102.218.2368_1" pos="250" freq="60" file="file1(auto).out.xml" freindlyPos="true" vTypes="auto"/>

<!-- AtoB; speed=80 km/h; 100m before 2 to 1 lane -->
<inductionLoop id="AtoB-3.1(auto)" lane="27333102.218.2968_0" pos="825" freq="60" file="file2(auto).out.xml" freindlyPos="true" vTypes="auto"/>
<inductionLoop id="AtoB-3.2(auto)" lane="27333102.218.2968_1" pos="825" freq="60" file="file2(auto).out.xml" freindlyPos="true" vTypes="auto"/>
```